# why after running updates, some of my apps on SD will get moved to device again?

Tags: android, mobile

I am not a guru in the mobile space. So if someone can give me some ideas on why this is happening, it would be great.

I have moved some apps, such as FB, Kindle, etc to SD card because my device storage is running out of space. However, I am noticing, whenever Google Play Store install updates, it moves them back to device. And I have to manually move them back to SD because my device storage is low.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem? Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general hardware/software tech support.

Comment: Try https://android.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because they programmatically choose prefered place to install.